# XQuery: sharing global variables across (imported) modules

Tags: module, global-variables, xquery

To my surprise, I'm wrestling with a quite basic XQuery question, namely what is the correct way to share global variables between a main XQuery module and imported library modules. Put simply, I would like to define a global variable somewhere that can be reused anywhere (i.e. in all (imported) XQuery modules), and am struggling to find the best place to declare such a variable.

Suppose I have following main XQuery (test.xq):

```
import module namespace global="global" at "global.xq";
import module namespace test2="test2" at "test2.xq";

declare variable $test := 'test!';

test2:echo()
```

This module imports following library modules:

- global.xq:

  ```
  module namespace global="global";

  declare variable $global:test := 'global!';
  ```
- test2.xq:
      module namespace test2="test2";

  ```
  import module namespace global="global" at "global.xq";

  declare function test2:echo() {
    $global:test
  };
  ```

This works, but leaves me with some questions:

- Is this the way to do it:

  - define global variables (e.g. $global:test) in a separate library module (e.g. global.xq)
  - import that module wherever it is needed to provide access to its variables

  ?
- Is there a way to access variables declared in the main XQuery module (e.g. $test) in imported library modules (e.g. test2.xq)?

Can anyone shed light on this? I guess the main reason why I find myself struggling with this concept is because I'm used to [eXist](http://exist-db.org/)'s behaviour, which is probably laxer than it should. In eXist, the test2.xq module can just refer to the $global:test variable without importing the global.xq module:

```
module namespace test2="test2";
declare namespace global="global";

declare function test2:echo() {
  $global:test
};
```

Since this works in eXist, but not in Saxon, I started wondering what is the correct way to define and use global variables in (imported) XQuery modules.

Kind regards,

Ron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently eXists takes the approach that might be familiar to you from XSLT.In there you can also refer to variables and parameters declared outside the current module through imports/includes of 'ancestor' modules (higher in the include/import chain).

**To my knowledge that is not conform the XQuery standard!**

It is obviously very practical to be able to use this, but there are a few good reasons why not to do so. Ideally, modules are self-contained, reuseable components, and that is no longer the case when they rely on such external params/vars. It would be better to pass in contextual information as a parameter to such functions. Doesn't always look elegant, but is better design in the end.

Some implementations provide an alternative option using redefinition of variable values. MarkLogic has the xdmp:set command, and I believe saxon has variable assignment too (or was that in XSLT?). You could use that to 'initialize' modules. Mind though that modules aren't objects, so try to avoid using such an approach to hold statefull information. It would also mean you'd rely on implementation specific functions. Unless you'd be able to use the update facility for that. Not sure that is intended to work that way though..

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm very well aware that I might have bumped into assumptions based on non-standard behaviour. Yet, I couldn't find many useful hints on the web concerning such design patterns. I'm not fond of vendor-specific extensions for such a basic need. Would you recommend the working approach in my original question (i.e. define global variables in a dedicated library module and import as needed) as the standard way to make global variables accessible to all (importing) XQuery modules? Or do you see other (conformant) possibilities?

Comment: @rvdb I'd recommend passing in such values through parameters to each call. It is very easy to gather lots of context info into a small XML fragment, and pass that around. It is by far most extensible and cleanest.

Importing a shared globals module like you did is the most sensible other option, unless you have good reason to want to have the initialize kind of behaviour I described..

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

What *are* these "variables" in your actual use case? Do they, as the name implies, need to be able to vary? (If so, putting them in a document may be the Right Thing to do). If they're just constants, the approach you gave -- putting them in a single module/namespace and importing that as necessary -- is probably the Right Thing.

Frankly, writing your modules to assume something defined elsewhere, but not defining where that elsewhere should be, strikes me as hazard-prone -- if for no other reason, by way of making it harder for a reader to follow the flow of control. As such, I'm a little unclear on why that behavior would be desirable.

Consider encapsulating your configuration in a document and passing that document as an argument to your function calls.

Comment: No, they'e constants; I'm thinking more of a configuration file containing app-specific values that can be used by generic code. The generic code then can serve for different apps, each with their own configuration values. 

I guess your second remark concerns the eXist behaviour I mentioned? In which case I do agree: I'd rather take a spec-compliant route.

Comment: @rvdb - ahh, gotcha. My personal approach for feeding in configuration values is to inject them via a configuration document, passed as a parameter to any call which needs such values. Right now, I'm passing this document to actual calls as a context parameter rather than storing it in the database at all, though that particular approach is something I'm not sure I'm sold on long-term... but either way, explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @rvdb ...actually, it looks like grtjn is independently suggesting the same approach; I'm reading that as some level of vindication/validation for my own usage. :)

Comment: charles and @grtjn: many thanks for your helpful insights! Though I'd like to accept both your answers, I'll apply the rule of the first. Thanks, guys.